# How do i import list of variables as choices for a charfield from outside the app?

Tags: python, django, models

I'm trying to make a select box in the admin that shows a list of objects in the database, outside the current app. Here is my model

```
from typefaces.models import Typeface

class Word(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    family_select = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Typeface.objects.all)
```

Unfortunately, Django tells me `'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).` But my attemps to make it iterable with `iter()` have yielded no success.

Comment: `iter` doesn't make things an iterable. You need to use `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a completely wrong way to do it. Relationships between models should be specified using OneToOneFields, ForeignKeys (one-to-many field) and ManyToManyFields. You should just change the CharField to this:

```
family = models.ForeginKey(Typeface, related_name='words')
```

If you have a specific reason for not using the generally acceptable way, please elaborate on that further to get an answer for that.

Comment: That is excellent. I changed to a OneToOneField and the problem was solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesEdmondson You can also mark the answer as correct then.